# Modifying HTML Elements with Python Dictionary in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am getting 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment, when trying to modify HTML elements using Beatiful Soup and a Python dictionary.

This is for a program that will create a HTML file from a template. The values to change are received from the user in a form. Here is the code I have at the moment

```
    data = {
        'banner-url': ['src', request.POST.get('banner_url')],
        'banner-link': ['href', request.POST.get('banner_link')],
        'title-text': ['text', request.POST.get('title-text')]
    }

    # Loop through the data dictionary and let Beautiful Soup find element with ID's that match the data[key]
    for key, value in data.items():
        _temp = soup.find(id=key).value[0] = value[1]
```

I would like to modify HTML elements using keys and values in a Python dictionary.

When I run the program I get the NoneType error instead of the element being modified. The error is on the line _temp = soup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign twice in the same line. And if bs4 doesn't find something it returns `None`. That might be the case here.
For your future problems with this I recommend you looking at [official bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc)

Comment: Thank for the help! Even when I have  soup.find(id=key).value[0] = value[1]  without _temp, it gives the same error. I can do this manually by finding each element individually but was olling for a way to just have everything in a loop!. Thanks though!

Comment: @GregStrydom you might want to show the error in your question.